# When to use constructor and when to pass in arguments

Tags: java, design-patterns

My general question is when to pass arguements to constructor vs when to pass it to the 
method of a class.
In general an object is "data" + "methods that act on a data".

I have a few options to design a class called DFS. Which of the following examples suite defination the best ?

Option 1: Graph passed in the constructor, source in a function.
Adv: Same DFS object would be reused with a different source.

```
public class DFS {
   Graph g;
   public DFS(Graph g) {
     this.g = g;
   }

   public void doDfs(int source) {
     // dfs computation
   }
}
```

Option 2: Constructor with 2 params and no polymorphism
Disadv: for each new source new object needs to be constructed.

```
public class DFS {
    Graph g;
    int source;   

    public DFS(Graph g, int source) {
      this.g = g;
      this.source = source;
    }

    public void doDfs() {
      // dfs computation
    }
 }
```

Option 3: Overload constructor
Adv: solves all our use cases.
Dis: Polymorphism is costly.

```
public class DFS {
   Graph g;
   int source;   

   public DFS(Graph g) {
     this.g = g;
   }

   public DFS(Graph g, int source) {
     this.g = g;
     this.source = source;
   }

   public void doDfs() {
      doDfs(source);
   }

   public void doDfs(int source) {
     // dfs computation
   }
}
```

Option 4: No constructor

```
public class DFS {

    DFS() { }

    public void doDFS(Graph g, int source) {
      this.g = g;
      this.source = source;
      // dfs computation
    }
 }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027135

Comment: What do you mean by "polymorphism"? I don't see any polymorphism here, nor do i see how it might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have something which is associated with the operations/definition of class, then it meant to be passed as constructor. Which also means, it would be highly desired to have it as `immutable`. For example:

```
public class DFS {
   final Graph g;
   public DFS(Graph g) {
     this.g = g;
   }

   public void doDfs(int source) {
     // dfs computation
   }
}
```

Here you know that the class `DFS` contains multiple methods (each with the own algorithm) to find the `DFS` of the graph `g`. In such cases you know that `g` is immutable and would be a pain to pass it along for every method call, hence better to make it a constructor argument. Some advantages:

1. No redundant argument to every method call.
2. If you wish to do some internal caching, you can do it. This works as everything is related to a known entity: `g`
3. Thread-Safety, No explicit locking. You would need it with setters.

In short, when you know something is not going change wrt to definition of class, make it as constructor argument. Have methods which uses those instance variables. Use Setters, when you know something can change.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of logic. When you have designed your class so that an object of the class needs particular data to be valid, then the data must be supplied in the constructor. You should also check that the object is actually passed by using `assert`.

But you could *choose* to design you class so that the data is added later. It depends on how you intend your class to be used - you should be designing your class for the users of it.

BTW, you comment in your post that "Polymorphism is costly". No, if polymorphism is what gets the job done for you, then it's not expensive. And it depends on what kind of polymorphism you mean as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer option 4. No constructor or minimal constructor makes it much easier to test the class with unit testing.

Also in larger projects I prefer to create new classes that only holds the parameters, and then use such a class as a parameter. If the same parameters are passed around a lot, it makes it much easier to make changes later without changing all the methods.